# How to get data by date using Youtube API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Im new to yt api and i was wondering how can i get for example top 50 channels by subscriber count with defined date, or in interval like 2018-2019?

Comment: It's a little bit unclear, what exactly don't you know. Haven't you found the Channels API? Here it is: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels. Don't you know how to get JSON with channels information? Don't you know how to make HTTP requests? Do you have troubles exactly with the case of interval or "by subscriber counter"? Please, specify the problem.

Comment: I think you might be looking for this documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list (you can do something like publishedAfter and publishedBefore, with type=channel, but there's I couldn't find order=subscriberCount option)

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)